# creating a class in python with a method. description below

Tags: python, class, object, methods, attributes

I need help with a code that is inspired by an online clothing shipment order. It has a Clothing class and 5 attributes (order num, list with the clothes in the cart, person's name, and a boolean stating if the order has been received.

Then, I have to make a method. This method should let the user add Clothing objects to the list of clothes based on the following condition: it has to be a Clothing item, it cannot be something random. The last condition is the user should be able to add more unless there is already 10 or more Clothing items in the cart.

I already made the Clothing class, but I am having trouble connecting everything and making the list as one of the attributes.

```py
class Clothing:
    def __init__(self, number, clothes = [], cusname, oreceieved):
        self.number= number
        self.clothes = clothes
        self.cusname = cusname
        self.oreceived = False
```

This is what I have so far.

*Note* I have a clothing file that will be imported, so I already have the data. It is the setup that I need help with.

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example! Show your code, sample inputs and outputs, and what you expected to get. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Sounds like you're having trouble creating an add method for the class based upon the conditions.  Is that right?

Comment: @webbpie--by "of a certain type" are you referring to static or run-time type checking?

Comment: @webbpie--setters and getters don't seem expedient here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216099/discussion-between-webbpie-and-darrylg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, since I don't know specifics about your data files, I'll just talk about the general structure you might want to shoot for. This answer will only discuss how to implement the add method, it won't go into how to do type checking for the other arguments you pass to the **init** function.

```
class Clothing:
    def __init__(self, number, clothes = [], cusname, oreceieved):
        self.number= number
        self.clothes = clothes
        self.cusname = cusname
        self.oreceived = False
        self.max_clothes = 10

    def add_clothes(self, clothing):
        # Start by ensuring that clothing is a clothing item
        if not self.is_clothing(clothing):
            return
        # Check to see if clothes list is 'full'
        if len(clothes) >= self.max_clothes:
            return
        # If valid article of clothing, and list not full, append
        self.clothes.append(clothing)

    def is_clothing(self, clothing):
        '''check that passed clothing is a valid clothing item'''
        # Open clothing data file, parse for passed clothing item, return
        # True if clothing item found in file, return False otherwise.
```